# trying to make canvas fill page under a title

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

i want the canvas to fill the whole webpage under the heading, maybe with a small margin between the edge of the canvas and the edge of the window. but i can't get it to fill the screen and now the title is next to it instead of above it. any help is appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>shark?</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .container {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
        canvas {
            background-color: dodgerblue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>shark?</h1>
        <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eh, why did you award the points to the other answer, when I added mine first?

Comment: sorry it was because I found the other answer more useful, as it allowed me to edit the margins and was the one I ended up using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the property `flex-direction: column;` to the container class to arrange the elements vertically.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>shark?</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden; /* Prevent scrollbars */
        }
        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column; /* Arrange elements vertically */
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
        h1 {
            margin-top: 20px; /* Add margin above the heading */
        }
        canvas {
            background-color: dodgerblue;
            margin: 10px; /* Add margin around the canvas */
            flex: 1; /* Allow the canvas to fill available vertical space */
            width: calc(100% - 20px); /* Account for margin */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>shark?</h1>
        <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use `flex-direction: column;` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) on the `.container` and then add a width to your `canvas`. The 90vw unit means set the width to "effectively" 90% the width of the viewport. Set that value to what you want.

Also remove `justify-content: center;` from your `.container` to achieve the desired result.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>shark?</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .container {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
        canvas {
            width: 90vw;
            background-color: dodgerblue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>shark?</h1>
        <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```